# Transferring a multidimensional array from mysql to php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I seem to be having a bit of trouble. The PHP portion seems to work well, but I can't seem to get the info over to the JS portion. Here is what I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <body>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("stuff") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Location, Latitude, Longitude FROM Places WHERE Latitude IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Location, Latitude, Longitude");
    $places = array();
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) !== false) {
        $places[] = $row;
    }
    ?>
    <script>
    function makeTableHTML(myArray) {
        var result = "<table border=1>";
        for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            result += "<tr>";
            for(var j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++){
                result += "<td>"+myArray[i][j]+"</td>";
            }
             result += "</tr>";
        }
    result += "</table>";
    return result;
    }
    var places = "<?php echo json_encode($places) ?>";
    makeTableHTML(places);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tested the PHP portion and it works just fine. I am fairly new to the JS and I am not sure how I can go about testing/debugging this. Any help would be appreciated.

I found the makeTableHTML function on here in hopes that it would help, but I didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP seems to be working. Also your javascrip HTML code generation seems to be ok. But you are no where writing the table into the DOM.

Therefore you have to select an DOM Element and write the result of makeTableHTML into it. 
For example:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].innerHTML += makeTableHTML(places);
```

In your code example it would make more sense to generate the table with PHP directly. Javascript only make sense if you want to dynamically change your site.

I don't know what you are trying to archieve here, but maybe you should look into ajax requests. But it is hard to say, without knowing what you want to create.

You also asked about howto debug javascript, of course you could use alert() to output any variable in your code. But in more complex cases it is advisable to use the debugger. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Tools/Debugger) for howto use it in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will be putting this into a Google Maps API via JS. In the end, I just need the info in an array to plot map points. It works if I write the array manually, but doesn't work if I use this. That led me to believe that array wasn't getting passed over. I am new to the whole DOM thing, so I will have to read up on it.

Comment: Ok, then your approach seems to be good. As I already mentioned you also should have a look at the debugger. If you already have worked with a debugger you shouldn't have any trouble in using it. There you can also manipulating the DOM or running javascript commands at runtime.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, even with the debugger. The 2D array can't be seen by it. It just appears to be the PHP script I have it set to. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Would you please post the output of the php script? Open the page in the browser and show the source code, then copy it into a jsfiddle e.g.

Comment: I am not sure how to go about doing that. I can do a print_r() in PHP, but I am trying to do a json_encode of that. I think the issue is with the transfer from PHP to JS. I googled around a bit, but everywhere seems to say that I am doing it correctly.

Comment: You are opening your script in a browser aren't you ? Then just press Ctrl+U to open source code view and copy all of this onto jsfiddle or any other code hosting service, and share the link here.

Comment: Yes, but I can't really run a jsfiddle as it connects do a database locally and returns about 10,000 rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103785/discussion-between-luca-adrian-and-user1911612).